# Misplaced \noalign error in table, but only when using include{}

Tags: tables, highlighting, xtable

I am using `xtable()` in `R` to create a LaTeX table that I import into a `.rnw` file via `\input{}`. As documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19921025/xtable-highlighting-rowcolor-shifted-down-one-row), I am attempting to highlight rows conditional upon a certain value of one variable.

The `R` side of my problem has been resolved. Now I am struggling with a LaTeX problem, which is why I am posting here.

The following `R` code creates my table:

```
  wd <- "yourpath"
  setwd(wd)
# create data frame
  my.df=data.frame(a=c(1:10),b=letters[1:10],c=c(1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1))

# identify index of rows to highlight
  row.i.1 <- which(my.df$c==1)

print(xtable(my.df),
      only.contents=TRUE,
      include.rownames=FALSE,
      include.colnames=FALSE,
      hline.after=NULL,
      type="latex",
      add.to.row=list(
        pos=list(as.list(row.i.1))[[1]],
        command=rep("\\rowcolor{green!20!white}",
                    length(seq(from=1,to=length(row.i.1),by=1)))),
      sanitize.text.function=identity,
      file="testtbl.tex"
```

Here are the contents of `testtbl.tex`:

```
% latex table generated in R 3.0.1 by xtable 1.7-1 package
% Tue Nov 12 10:23:27 2013
   1 & a & 1.00 \\ 
   \rowcolor{green!20!white}  2 & b & 1.00 \\ 
   \rowcolor{green!20!white}  3 & c & 0.00 \\ 
    4 & d & 0.00 \\ 
    5 & e & 1.00 \\ 
   \rowcolor{green!20!white}  6 & f & 1.00 \\ 
   \rowcolor{green!20!white}  7 & g & 0.00 \\ 
    8 & h & 0.00 \\ 
    9 & i & 1.00 \\ 
   \rowcolor{green!20!white} 10 & j & 1.00 \\ 
   \rowcolor{green!20!white}
```

The row highlighting is shifted down one row for some reason. A commenter on SO instructed me to change `pos=list(as.list(row.i.1))[[1]],` to `pos=list(as.list(row.i.1-1))[[1]],` (adding the `-1`), which gives the correct assignment:

```
% latex table generated in R 3.0.1 by xtable 1.7-1 package
% Tue Nov 12 10:26:16 2013
  \rowcolor{green!20!white}  1 & a & 1.00 \\ 
   \rowcolor{green!20!white}  2 & b & 1.00 \\ 
    3 & c & 0.00 \\ 
    4 & d & 0.00 \\ 
   \rowcolor{green!20!white}  5 & e & 1.00 \\ 
   \rowcolor{green!20!white}  6 & f & 1.00 \\ 
    7 & g & 0.00 \\ 
    8 & h & 0.00 \\ 
   \rowcolor{green!20!white}  9 & i & 1.00 \\ 
   \rowcolor{green!20!white} 10 & j & 1.00 The problem now comes when I try to include this table in a `.rnw` file.
```

(1) If I paste the table directly into my `.rnw` file, everything works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl, xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{lll}
  \toprule
  var1 & var2 & var3 \\
  \midrule
% latex table generated in R 3.0.1 by xtable 1.7-1 package
% Tue Nov 12 10:26:16 2013
  \rowcolor{green!20!white}  1 & a & 1.00 \\ 
   \rowcolor{green!20!white}  2 & b & 1.00 \\ 
    3 & c & 0.00 \\ 
    4 & d & 0.00 \\ 
   \rowcolor{green!20!white}  5 & e & 1.00 \\ 
   \rowcolor{green!20!white}  6 & f & 1.00 \\ 
    7 & g & 0.00 \\ 
    8 & h & 0.00 \\ 
   \rowcolor{green!20!white}  9 & i & 1.00 \\ 
   \rowcolor{green!20!white} 10 & j & 1.00 \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

(2) However, if I try to import the table via `include`, which is what I need to do for reproducibility, I get the following error: `Error: testtbl.tex:3: Misplaced \noalign`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl, xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{lll}
  \toprule
  var1 & var2 & var3 \\
  \midrule
  \input{testtbl}
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

(3) If I go back and use the original `xtable` code, `pos=list(as.list(row.i.1))[[1]]`, thus not subtracting 1, the `pdf` will compile, but my highlighting is shifted.

So my question is: Why am I getting a `Misplaced \noalign` when grabbing my table contents via `include` (2) but not when copying and pasting the exact same content directly into the document (1). The fact that (3) will compile (but with incorrect highlighting) makes me think it has something to do with how I try to correct the shifted highlighting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is linked to the fact that the `LaTeX` `\input` is "non-expandable". Two solutions are proposed in the code, either use the `TeX` original primitive or first input the file contents in a macro, using, for facility the `catchfile` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl, xcolor}
% Plain old TeX is the best!
\makeatletter\let\expandableinput\@@input\makeatother
% alternative
% \usepackage{catchfile}
% \CatchFileDef{\testtblasmacro}{testtbl}{} % don't forget empty braces

\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{lll}
  \toprule
  var1 & var2 & var3 \\
  \midrule
  \expandableinput testtbl.tex
% or 
% \testtblasmacro
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: table with colors]

Comment: great, @jfbu. thanks! i had no idea about `\expandableinput`. that works for me.