# Longtable & \input - Misplaced \noalign and \omit

Tags: longtable, input, hline

SOLVED! (see below)

I'm trying to create a `longtable` that uses a generated input file.

This is my main file:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[left=1cm, right=1cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{longtable}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|}
        \hline
        Name & First Name & ID \\
        \hline\hline
        
        \input{generated.tex}

        \hline
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

This is the content of `generated.tex`:

```
Ebug & Dieter & 515177 \\\hline
Mority & Joe & 515192 \\\hline
Underland & Barbara & 515211 \\\hline
Ebug & Denis & 515230 \\\hline
Mustermann & Michelle & 515240 \\\hline
Onemore & Karsten & 515253 \\\hline
Astone & Leonie & 515271 \\\hline
```

However, when using `\input{generated.tex}`, I get the following errors during compilation:

```
! Misplaced \noalign.
\hline ->\noalign 
                  {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \penalty \@M \futurelet \@let@token \LT@@h...
l.25        \hline
                
? H
I expect to see \noalign only after the \cr of
an alignment. Proceed, and I'll ignore this case.

? 
! Misplaced \omit.
\multispan ->\omit 
                   \@multispan 
l.26    \end
          {longtable}
? H
I expect to see \omit only after tab marks or the \cr of
an alignment. Proceed, and I'll ignore this case.
```

*Note that I'm using to output of the interactive mode here to get more info on the errors.*

These errors disappear if I remove the last `\hline`.
Apart from those errors, I also get a weird extra row at the end of my table. This also doesn't disappear when removing the last `\hline`.

All the errors and weird last row disappear when I simply add the contents of the `generated.tex` into the main file. This confuses me because `\input` is supposed to be the equivalent of simply adding the content of the specified file in its place. Does anyone have any experiences with this? From the error messages it looks like the problem is a carriage return at the end of the `generated.tex` file.

**SOLUTION:**

As Phelype Oleinik mentioned in the comments, this has to do with a change made to `\input` in fall of 2020. More info can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/583927/misplaced-noalign-error-with-input-in-a-table-after-the-2020-fall-latex-releas/583939#583939).

The solution is to define a custom command `\expandableinput` before the beginning of the `document`:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn % providing \expandableinput
\cs_new:Npn \expandableinput #1
{ \use:c { @@input } { \file_full_name:n {#1} } }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Then this new command can be used instead of `\input`.

Comment: Try using `\expandableinput` from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/583939/134574)

Comment: That worked a charm! Hard to find if you don't know what you have to look for. Thanks a lot

Comment: Glad it worked!  Don't worry, some issues (like this one) are hard to spot if you don't already know what you're looking for.  I'll link this as a duplicate