# \input inside tikzpicture differs from inserting manually

Tags: tikz-pgf, miktex, input

using an up-to-date MiKTeX installation I'm trying to plot a graph in TikZ, where the `\draw` command with the coordinates is input from an external file. The `\draw` command is not closed by a semicolon inside the file though, because its options like `[-latex]` should be assignable within the main file.
When I insert the file contents directly into the main file, everything works fine, but when I use `\input{myfilename}` to insert the file contents, I get the error

```
Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?. \input{myfilename}
```

Here are the MWEs:

This works fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}
        \draw plot[smooth] coordinates { %
            (           1,            0) %
            (         0.5,         -0.5) %
            (           0,            0) %
        }%
        [-latex];
    \end{scope}
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But this produces the error:

```
\begin{filecontents}{genplot}
\draw plot[smooth] coordinates { %
    (           1,            0) %
    (         0.5,         -0.5) %
    (           0,            0) %
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}
        \input{genplot}%
        [-latex];
    \end{scope}
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Strangely this **was working fine** until at least a year ago (when I last compiled the document). So something in the behaviour of using `\input` inside a TikZ picture must have changed since then.
Can someone enlighten me or does anyone have a solution where I don't need to edit the content of the external file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more or less the same issue as [this one](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/982) caused by the change described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/583939/134574), and can be solved using the same workaround; add this to your preamble:

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \expandableinput #1
  { \use:c { @@input } { \file_full_name:n {#1} } }
\AddToHook{env/tikzpicture/begin}
  { \cs_set_eq:NN \input \expandableinput }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

The code above will replace LaTeX's `\input` by `\expandableinput` inside the `tikzpicture` environment.

> [image]

```latex
\begin{filecontents}{genplot}
\draw plot[smooth] coordinates { %
    (           1,            0) %
    (         0.5,         -0.5) %
    (           0,            0) %
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \expandableinput #1
  { \use:c { @@input } { \file_full_name:n {#1} } }
\AddToHook{env/tikzpicture/begin}
  { \cs_set_eq:NN \input \expandableinput }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}
        \input{genplot}%
        [-latex];
    \end{scope}
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```