# Misplaced \noalign because \input before booktabs rule

Tags: texlive, booktabs

In a large project, I reuse with `\input` tabular rows stored as child files. This has worked perfectly in the past, but in my texlive 2021 this fail when a `booktabs` rule follow the input. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\toprule
    1 & 2 & 3\\
\midrule    
\input{foo}
\bottomrule % This causes the error
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Where `foo.tex` is simply `a & b & c \\`.

It fails also ending the tabular rows with `\tabularnewline` or `\cr`. The  funny point is that `\bottomrule` works fine inside `foo.tex` (`a & b & c \\\bottomrule`) but this is not good a solution because `foo.tex` could be needed in another table, and not necessarily as the last row. AFAIK, unlike `\include`, `\input` add strictly the content of the file, so it should be irrelevant if `\bootomrule` is  inside or outside the child file, but is it not. I wonder if there is a better fix that `\input{foot}\\[-12pt]\bottomrule`.

Comment: Input has now hooks and so is more complicated.  Search for an expandable input on the site, there were already some questions about this.

Comment: Consider using [`catchfile`](//ctan.org/pkg/catchfile) to store the contents of `foo.tex` inside a macro that you can then use (`\CatchFileDef{\foo}{foo.tex}{}`).

Comment: @Fran https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/583939/134574

Comment: @Fran I'd recommend you do something like `\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \expandableinput #1
  { \use:c { @@input } { \file_full_name:n {#1} } }
\AddToHook{env/tabular/begin}
  { \cs_set_eq:NN \input \expandableinput }
\ExplSyntaxOff` (similar to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/600710/134574)).  Completely overriding `\input` may break other things down the road.  The above will only change `\input` in a `tabular` environment.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I will need also for tabulary and tabularx, but  anyway is a good  idea since only modify the preamble. Consider to expand your comment in an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your issue is the same as [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/583939/134574) and similar to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/600710/134574).  Newer `\input` adds unexpandable tokens in the way of `\noalign` (from `\bottomrule`), then when the `\noalign` is seen it is too late and you get the error.  With no changes to the document body, you can add this to your preamble:

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \expandableinput #1
  { \use:c { @@input } { \file_full_name:n {#1} } }
\AddToHook{env/tabular/begin}
  { \cs_set_eq:NN \input \expandableinput }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

The code above will redefine `\input` to be `\expandableinput` in all `tabular` environments.  To add that to more environments, simply replicate the two lines and change the environment name:

```latex
\AddToHook{env/tabularx/begin} % also for tabularx
  { \cs_set_eq:NN \input \expandableinput }
\AddToHook{env/tabulary/begin} % and for tabulary
  { \cs_set_eq:NN \input \expandableinput }
```

Comment: Phelype, I'm having the same issue: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/622212/lyx-misplace-noalign-include-tex-table I tried adding your suggestion to preamble but that did not fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: @DavidZentler-Munro In your code you seem to be using a custom `\estinput` command, so you'd have to change `\cs_set_eq:NN \input \expandableinput` to `\cs_set_eq:NN \estinput \expandableinput` in the code above

Comment: Great thanks: that works!

Comment: Weirdly this solution works in lyx but when I try to export to tex and run from tex it does not work (I get the same misplace noalign error). Any idea why this might be?

Comment: @DavidZentler-Munro No idea.  I've never used LyX.  If you send me the exported `.tex` file I can investigate

Comment: I've added tex file to answer below (let me know if I could provide it in a more useful format)

Comment: @DavidZentler-Munro It's hard to tell without the contents of the file, but the path `/tables/MWE2.tex` looks suspicious.  In a Linux machine that points to a folder `tables` in the root directory (which is very unusual).  Try with `\estauto{tables/MWE2.tex}{3}{c}`.  But please, don't post additional code in an answer (use some service like https://pastebin.com):  that space is reserved for actual answers only.

Answer (score 0):

I will provide an alternative solution with [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package of version 2022B (2022-06-01), by using `evaluate` option in `functional` library:

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{foo.tex}
  a & b & c \\
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs,functional}
\begin{document}
\begin{booktabs}[evaluate=\fileInput]{ccc}
\toprule
  1 & 2 & 3\\
\midrule
  \fileInput{foo}
\bottomrule
\end{booktabs}
\end{document}
```

where `\fileInput` function is provided by `functional` library.

[image]