# \usepackage{booktabs} giving an error

Tags: tables, booktabs

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % full-width
    \topskip        =   20pt
    \parskip        =   10pt
    \parindent      =   0 pt
    \baselineskip   =   15pt
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsfonts, amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{setspace}  % line spacing
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{rotating}  % for sidewaystable

\usepackage{threeparttable}    
\usepackage{dcolumn}    % aligning decimals
    \newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}

\let\estinput=\input % define a new input command so that we can still flatten the document

\newcommand{\estauto}[3]{
        \vspace{.75ex}{
            %\textsymbols% Note the added command here
            \begin{tabular}{l*{#2}{#3}}
            \toprule
            \estinput{#1}
            \bottomrule
            \addlinespace[.75ex]
            \end{tabular}
            }
        }

\newcommand{\sym}[1]{\rlap{#1}}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tabulary}

\title{Project Name}
\author{X Y Z}
\date{September 2021}

\begin{document}
\maketitle


\section*{Summary Statistics (Tables)}
\subsection*{Consent}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{caption}
    \label{tab:meetattend}
    \estauto{xyz.tex}{8}{c}\\
    \small{\textit{Notes:}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I apologise for my earlier post. I am very new to the forum and latex and posting for the first time. I have a file named xyz.tex in the project which looks like this:

```
            &\multicolumn{8}{c}{var name}                                                               \\
            &           N&        Mean&          SD&         Min&     10th p.&      Median&     90th p.&         Max\\
\midrule
x     &         a&       b&       c&           0&           1&           1&           1&           1\\
y &         120&       0.825&       0.382&           0&           0&           1&           1&           1\\
z     &         243&       0.778&       0.417&           0&           0&           1&           1&           1\\
```

I get an error while compiling the pdf on overlead but when I remove \usepackage{booktabs}, the pdf is rendered but the table has no lines etc. I am not sure how to paste the error. I am not sure why that is happening. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Please provide a full [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) including an example table so we know what the problem is.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  If I put that into Overleaf along with a document class and a basic document, I don't get an error.

Comment: It might be a conflict with your document class, so we need to know what that is. Always post a complete, compiliable-as-is document that is as minimal as possible to produce the error in question.

Comment: you need to show the exact error copied from the log file, no one can debug a vague "compilation error" if you do not say what the error is and do not provide an example that makes the error.

Comment: I think the issue comes from using `\input` inside the table with `\bottomrule` following right after it. It's the [same problem in this question here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/611786/misplaced-noalign-because-input-before-booktabs-rule). Try the code suggested by [the accepted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/611803/411) and see if it fixes it.

Comment: @frabjous, you are right. I deleted my comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Both of the solutions posted here worked!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
    \begin{filecontents}{xyz.txt}
    & \multicolumn{8}{c}{var name} \\
    \cmidrule(l){2-9}
    & N     & Mean  & SD    & Min   & 10th p.   & Median & 90th p.  & Max   \\
    \midrule
x   & a     & b     & c     & 0     & 1         & 1      & 1        & 1     \\
y   & 120   & 0.825 & 0.382 & 0     & 0         & 1      & 1        & 1     \\
z   & 243   & 0.778 & 0.417 & 0     & 0         & 1      & 1        & 1     
    \end{filecontents}
    
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{setspace}  % line spacing
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{rotating}  % for sidewaystable

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}    % aligning decimals
    \newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\let\estinput=\input % define a new input command so that we can still flatten the document

\newcommand{\estauto}[3]{
    \begin{tabular}{l*{#2}{#3}}
    \toprule
    \estinput{#1}  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
                        }

\newcommand{\sym}[1]{\rlap{#1}}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{Project Name}
\author{X Y Z}
\date{September 2021}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section*{Summary Statistics (Tables)}
\subsection*{Consent}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{caption}
    \label{tab:meetattend}
\estauto{xyz.txt}{8}{c}     \\ % <--- added \\

    \small{\textit{Notes:}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

In comparison with your MWE are differences in:

- how the table is set
- how tale is inserted in document

Compilation result is:

[image]