# Error when trying to input an external file with xltabular package `\hline ->\noalign`

Tags: tables, align, external-files, subfiles, xltabular

I am trying to stack several tables one on another. For this I am using `xltabular` packages. I want to input text from another file. The following code works without problem when removing / commenting out the line:

```
\input{so_text.txt}
```

however if I remove / comment out the following lines (and want to input the exact same content with `\input{so_text.txt}` with the file containing that text:

```
blasasfd&1&h&bla\\
blasasfd&2&h&bla \\
blasasfd&5&h&bla \\
```

I get the following error message:

```
\hline ->\noalign
                  {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \hrule \@height \arrayrulewidth \futurelet...
l.14     \end{xltabular}
```

Here is the code

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

{
    \begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{| p{3cm} p{2.4cm} p{2.4cm} p{2.4cm}| }
    \caption{text} \label{key}\\
    \endlastfoot
        \hline
 \textbf{Bla}&\textbf{ a}&\textbf{b}&\textbf{ c}\\ 
% \input{so_text.txt}

blasasfd&1&h&bla\\
blasasfd&2&h&bla \\
blasasfd&5&h&bla \\
        \hline
    \end{xltabular} 
}
\end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This **is** a well known problem and has been discussed several times on the site. It is not related to `xltabular` as it also happens in `tabular`. See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/583939/3929

Comment: Many thanks @daleif