# Inputting data from external file causes misplaced \noalign error

Tags: tables, input

I want to be able to process data using a python script and write it to an external file which can be imported into a latex table environment.

The data is formatted exactly as it would be in the main `.tex` file (separated by `&`, with `\\` at the end of each row), so i was hoping I would be able to just use the `\input` command to input it directly into the latex source when it compiles, but it comes up with a misplaced `\noalign` error and doesn't display the bottom rule of the table.

Below is a minimal worked example where `\input` is used, which creates the error - along with a counter-example, where the same data is written directly into the latex source which works fine:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs} 

\begin{filecontents}{test.tab}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t]
\centering
\caption{Test table (input)}
\begin{tabular}{lrrr} \toprule
test 1 & test 2 & test 3 & test 4\\ \midrule
%
\input{test.tab}
%
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\caption{Test table (no input)}
\begin{tabular}{lrrr} \toprule
test 1 & test 2 & test 3 & test 4\\ \midrule
%
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
%
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

this produces:

[image]

Curiously enough, if I put the entire tabular environment into the file, and then use `\input{test.tab}` within the table environment tags, it works fine:

```latex
\begin{filecontents}{test.tab}
\begin{tabular}{lrrr} \toprule
test 1 & test 2 & test 3 & test 4\\ \midrule
%
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
%
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{filecontents}
```

but I would rather not do that, as I want to be able to edit the table itself easily, and don't want to have to re-generate all the data (or edit all of the files manually) every time I make a change.

Is there a simple way of inputting data directly into a table from an external file using the `\input` command (or something similar) like this? or do I have to use something like `pgfplotstables` to parse my data first?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/144640/219947

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an expanded input there:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs} 

\begin{filecontents}{test.tab}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
\end{filecontents}

\makeatletter
\def\expinput#1{\@@input#1 }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t]
\centering
\caption{Test table (input)}
\begin{tabular}{lrrr} \toprule
test 1 & test 2 & test 3 & test 4\\ \midrule
%
\expinput{test.tab}
%
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\caption{Test table (no input)}
\begin{tabular}{lrrr} \toprule
test 1 & test 2 & test 3 & test 4\\ \midrule
%
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
%
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]